# Read an image with the alpha channel and EXIF rotation

Tags: image, opencv

I'm using OpenCV to read a PNG image in Python. I need to read the image in RGBA and respect the possible EXIF flags, such as image rotation.

When I try to read the image via `cv2.imread("path", cv2.IMREAD_UNCHANGED)`, the EXIF flags are ignored (as per the documentation).

When I try to read the image via `cv2.imread("path", cv2.IMREAD_ANYCOLOR)`, alpha channel is erased.

Is there a way to have both? Should I use another lib (like PIL)?

Comment: are you saying that `ANYCOLOR` *did* respect EXIF rotation information? that would be strange! -- guessing here... maybe OpenCV only handles exif for jpegs, not for other formats. -- you could file this as a bug/feature on opencv's github. -- if PIL does it right, sure, use it. just watch the channel order. both PIL and OpenCV can interoperate through numpy arrays.

Comment: @christoph-rackwitz, as per [the doc](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d4/da8/group__imgcodecs.html#ga288b8b3da0892bd651fce07b3bbd3a56), all the reading modes BUT `IMREAD_IGNORE_ORIENTATION` and `IMREAD_UNCHANGED` respect EXIF rotation, so this is expected behaviour. Though, the guess about JPEG vs PNG sounds like it could be it, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using PIL and rotating the image from the EXIF data manually. Here is a snippet that helps in dealing with the rotation:

```py
import cv2 
import numpy as np 
from PIL import Image

_EXIF_ORIENTATION_FLAG_ID = 0x112
 _EXIF_ORIENTATION_2_OPENCV_ROTATION = {
     3: cv2.ROTATE_180, 
    6: cv2.ROTATE_90_CLOCKWISE,
     8: cv2.ROTATE_90_COUNTERCLOCKWISE 
} 

# ...

with Image.open(path) as pil_image: 
    pixels = np.array(pil_image) 
    exif = pil_image.getexif() 
if exif is not None and _EXIF_ORIENTATION_FLAG_ID in exif:
     orientation = exif.get(_EXIF_ORIENTATION_FLAG_ID) 
    if orientation is not None and orientation != 1: 
        pixels = cv2.rotate(pixels, EXIF_ORIENTATION_2_OPENCV_ROTATION[orientation])
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually there is a way to have both.

```
cv2.imread("path", cv2.IMREAD_UNCHANGED ^ cv2.IMREAD_IGNORE_ORIENTATION)
```

Tested with `opencv-python == 4.9.0.80`